# how to refer to a command-line argument in another module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner for programming. I am writing a package now. There are two scripts. The first script is to create a file that is to be used by the second script. In the first script, the file is a command-line parameter,

```
parser.add_argument('file_to_be_created', nargs='+', type=argparse.FileType('w'), help='create a file'),
```

and I use

```
args.file_to_be_created
```

to reference to it. My question is that how I refer to the file in the second script?

Comment: Normally, you just pass it as an argument to the function from the other script that needs it, or to the constructor for the object with the method that needs it. Is there a reason that won't work here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the second script, I need to import the first script, and use args.file_to_be_created  as in the first script to refer to it?

Comment: Do you actually have two _scripts_, as in things that get run independently as programs, or one script and one module? Normally, you just have one script. If it needs to call functions defined elsewhere, or create instances of classes defined elsewhere, it imports the modules that define them. And then it can pass any values it wants—including that `args.file_to_be_created` value—to those functions or classes.